# Hashmaps or full fledged caches?

Tags: java, caching, hashmap, guava, concurrenthashmap

There are several open-source cache implementations available in Java, like Guava Cache, Caffeine, etc. On the other hand, we can also use a Java hashmap to perform simple caching.
I found an [article](https://cruftex.net/2016/03/16/Java-Caching-Benchmarks-2016-Part-1.html) comparing the benchmarks of different caches and concurrent Hash Maps. Hashmap seems a clear winner in the benchmarks.
My use case is to store around 10-20 thousand String key-value pairs. The cache will be updated (Only updates and addition are allowed, no eviction) at regular intervals say 5 minutes.
Does it make any sense to use open-source cache implementations which provide more features rather than sticking with the Hash Map?


***Edit 1:*** Answering @JayC667 questions

1. Will there be any evictions/removals from the HashMap? 
   There will be no evictions at all. However, some values can be updated
2. What is the concurrency requirement? 
   A single thread is allowed to perform the write operation and multiple threads are allowed to read from caches and stale read is something I can live with.

Comment: I would say "*it depends*". Deploying a ready-to-use library has the benefit that most of them only need a handful of annotations to run. Implementing a cache with `HashMap` will most likely result in more handwritten code, that should also be tested. Is performance really a concern? ["*premature optimization is the root of all evil*" -- Donald Ervin Knuth: *Computer Programming as an Art* (1974), p. 671](https://dl.acm.org/ft_gateway.cfm?id=361612&ftid=289767)

Comment: Also, the article cited is from 2016. I would recommend to re-run the benchmark with a more recent JVM (at least Java 11 since it is the current LTS, or Java 17, since it should be released this month and it is the next LTS).

Comment: Yeah. I'd be REALLY surprised if there were HashMaps out there that are considerably faster than the one we already have, unless they use some very different means of mapping. Set the size parameter and resize behaviors right, there should not be much difference. Most importance - after all - would be your `.hashCode()` implementation if you were using your own Classes as keys...

Comment: Keep in mind that when using HashMaps, you can provide an initial capacity and a load factor. It will be a good idea to keep the same HashMap instance with a sufficient initial capacity to prevent losing runtime on allocating more memory and rehashing all entries.

Comment: Deploying a ready-to-use library certainly have it's own benefits @Turing85 but performance is one of the key concerns here and on the JVM version part I cited the article as the project I'm working on is stuck on java 8.

Comment: @JayC667 As I mentioned that I will be using String as keys, so I don't think `.hashCode()` implementation will come into the picture. Also, I could not understand what you mean by, _" I'd be REALLY surprised if there were HashMaps out there that are considerably faster than the one we already have"_

Comment: Real caches are about 1) good eviction and 2) good concurrency. If you need neither, no point in checking out libraries. So two more important questions you should answer in your question: 1) Will there be any evictions/removals from the HashMap, maybe even with special rules? Your question implies NO, but just to be sure... 2) Do you need multithreaded WRITE access? Or multithreaded read/write at the same time? Because if you're only having one thread writing and all others reading, the only pitfall would be re-sizing and re-hashing, so defining good load factors and capacity would fix this.

Comment: @Pieter12345 rehashing is what I'm mostly concerned with in the hashmap implementation of the Cache. The hashmap instance will be a singleton to make sure the same object is being used at all places but initial capacity and load factor we definitely want to fine tune.

Comment: @ad_03 I cannot imagine that if we are in a single-threaded, `hashCode()`-based environment, that there is anything noticeably faster then a `java.util.HashMap` (Java 1.8+) with proper initial size/capacity and a good loadFactor. But if you said you needed removal/eviction strategies, or parallel read/write operations etc, there surely are better implementations out there. Or also, I need to add, improved memory requirements.

Comment: @ad_03 If you're worried about the rehashing, why not simply set the initial capacity to 30'000 or 40'000? Or even better: 2 times the amount of your elements, if you can estimate it at start. And you can even have some additional thread record the size and store it in a file, so that if the needed capacity increases over time (as most software requirements do), and the program is restarted, you will start at the ideal size again.

Comment: @JayC667 added the detailed info about the eviction and concurrency requirements. I think going with the concurrent hash map implementation with fine-tuned capacity and load factor is the way forward for this use case.

Comment: That's a nice idea @JayC667, will do that to get proper load size estimation even if in the future the requirement changes. They usually change.

Comment: Instead of a `ConcurrentHashMap`, consider instead using an immutable map that is recreated and atomically swap the reference to it. This way no unexpected writes can occur, readers can use the stale reference safely, and there are no other synchronization requirements. By using `Map.copyOf` there is no need to worry about load factors as it has already been heavily optimized by taking advantage of not being able to grow (e.g. uses open addressing versus closed addressing for better cpu cache efficiencies). I am glad you are not using a Guava/Caffeine (author) as those are not a fit here.